# How to implement a filter option in QTableWidget

Tags: qt, filter, qtablewidget

In my application, I have `QTableWidget` displaying multiple rows, a line edit to enter a string and a push button.

The requirement says, upon clicking on the push button, the same `QTableWidget` should show only rows which contain the string entered into the line edit.

I thought of using a `QSortFilterProxyModel`, but `QTableWidget` has `setModel(...)` method private, so I am unable to use `QSortFilterProxyModel` in this case.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using a sort/filter proxy is probably overkill for this anyway.

It's a matter of iterating through all of your QTableWidgetItem objects, determining if their text matches the filter and calling QTableView::setRowHidden() as needed.

For example:

```
QString filter = textEdit->text();
for( int i = 0; i < table->rowCount(); ++i )
{
    bool match = false;
    for( int j = 0; j < table->columnCount(); ++j )
    {
        QTableWidgetItem *item = table->item( i, j );
        if( item->text().contains(filter) )
        {
            match = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    table->setRowHidden( i, !match );
}
```

Comment: Or, we can simply use `QTableWidget.findItems(criteria, Qt.MatchContains)` which will return list of cell matching `criteria`

Answer (score 27):

I HIGHLY recommend going about this in the following way! This is how it is meant to be done in Qt.

Look at the [tutorial on Qt Model/View Programming](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html). The problem is that QTableWidget is a convenience class that hides the Model/View stuff for you. In your case, you can't (or shouldn't) ignore the Model/View structure Qt provides.

What you will need to do:

1. Use a `QTableView` instead of a `QTableWidget`.
2. Subclass `QAbstractItemModel` and implement `data()` (for reading), and all the other functions you need from the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#subclassing). This is the trickiest part, but refer to the above link for a walkthrough of how to do this.
3. Create a `QSortFilterProxyModel` and `setModel()` of the `QTableView` to it.
4. `setSourceModel()` of your `QSortFilterProxyModel` to your subclassed model.
5. Set the string you want to filter on using `setFilterFixedString()` or `setFilterRegExp()` in your `QSortFilterProxyModel`

Let me know if this helps. This is far more professional, and in the long run, elegant, than iterating through all the elements in your table.

Comment: I STRONGLY support that ;)

Things tend to start simple, and at some point you are not only hitting the barriers with other "brute force" methods but probably have lots more work to re-implement a model/view approach.

In other words: If something is an overkill (like written above) can't be judged in the beginning...